# WordPress Object Oriented plugin development

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, oop

Hello I am creating a plugin using WordPress, because the scale of this plugin is pretty big I am attempting to use OOP to implement what I need.

The way I am using it is that in the main plugin file I am including all the classes, then when `plugins_loaded` action is fired I make an instance of that function to fire up the `__construct`.

All of my classes are extending a helper class so I am adding `parent::__construct` in all my classes `__construct` function.

In the helper class I have defined bunch of `init` actions.

The code example:

```
// main plugin function code
require_once('include/helper.php');
require_once('includes/database.php');

add_action('plugins_loaded', array('helper', 'get_instance'));
add_action('plugins_loaded', array('database', 'get_instance'));

// end of main plugin function

// helper class code
class helper {
    function __construct() {
        add_action('init', 'function_name_1');
        add_action('init', 'function_name_2');
        add_action('init', 'function_name_3');
        add_action('init', 'function_name_4');
        add_action('init', 'function_name_5');
    )

    private $instance;
    static public function get_instance() {
        if (NULL === self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new helper();
        }
        return $instance;
    }
}

// one sample class code
// I probably have like 8 or 10 of these classes

class database extends helper {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        add_action('init', 'inner_function_name_1');
    }
    private $instance;
    static public function get_instance() {
        if (NULL === self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new helper();
        }
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this way of coding efficient if not please suggest the best way.
2. I have like 8 or 10 classes that does the exact same thing which causing the helper `__construct` function being loaded that many times so the `init` action will fire each time, Is that a problem and if that is how can I avoid it?

Comment: An object encapsulates a _task,_ a _combination of state and behavior_ or a _data structure_. Your many static dependencies on code outside of the object's scope are making the classes pretty much anti-OOP.

Comment: When you use a singleton pattern on all of your classes it can't be OOP, but leaving theory aside, how is this a wordpress specific question? It looks more like a generic PHP or OOP question

Comment: Because of the actions being loaded in `__construct`

Comment: Never register callbacks in a constructor. That makes your code almost impossible to test.

Comment: Not sure why you'd force the parent constructor to run with every new child.

Comment: Thanks you guys your comments made me realize a lot of stuff, Thanks

Comment: I think this question is way too broad and not really WordPress specific. Try to learn the basics first, limit yourself to a very strict set of rules. Recommended reading: [Object Calisthenics](https://github.com/object-calisthenics/phpcs-calisthenics-rules). If you hit a _WordPress specific_, isolated problem, your question is very welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things stand out.

- Don't load all your classes and files up front.

Load admin class when 
[`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) hooks fire and front-end classes when front-end hooks fire. Just think about lazy loading as much as possible.

- If `database` is an extension of `helper` then why initialize the base class?

That should be taken care of by `database`.

- Why hook [`'init'`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) multiple times?

Create an [`'init'`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) function and add one hook:

```
add_action('init', array($this,'my_init');
```

- Classes should be `CamelCase`

Don't make a class `lowercase`, ever.

- Maybe a better way than [`__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)?

In other languages it's not ideal to put actions in the initializer for the instance. Consider [`__invoke()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) as an alternatives. Unless you think someone might use the initializer later on...

```
self::$instance = new helper(); // __construct
self::$instance(); // __invoke
```

---

http://wppb.me/ does an interesting job of separating out admin loading from front-end loading.

And @toscho had a good link to https://github.com/object-calisthenics/phpcs-calisthenics-rules

---

Note: This is a rough outline of what I was thinking but I haven't tested it.

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'HelperClasses' ) ) {

    class HelperClasses {

        public static function initialize() {

            add_action( 'init', array ( 'HelperClasses', 'init' ) );
        }

        public static function init() {
            require_once( __DIR__ . '/inc/helper.php' );
            require_once( __DIR__ . '/inc/database.php' );
        }
    }

    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array ( 'HelperClasses', 'initialize' ) );
}
```

**/inc/helper.php**

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Helper' ) ) {

    /**
     * Class Helper
     *
     * Loaded via HelperClasses on `init`
     */
    class Helper {

        private static $_instance;

        public static function instance() {

            if ( ! isset( static::$_instance ) ) {
                $singleton = new Helper();
                static::$_instance = $singleton;
                $singleton();
            }

            return static::$_instance;
        }

        public function __invoke() {
            // TODO: Implement __invoke() method.
        }
    }
}
```

**/inc/database.php**

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Database' ) ) {

    if ( ! class_exists( 'Helper' ) ) {
        wp_die('Helper class required');
    }

    /**
     * Class Database
     *
     * Loaded via HelperClasses on `init`
     */
    class Database extends Helper {

        private static $_instance;

        public static function instance() {

            if ( ! isset( static::$_instance ) ) {
                $singleton = new Database();
                static::$_instance = $singleton;
                $singleton();
            }

            return static::$_instance;
        }

        public function __invoke() {
            // TODO: Implement __invoke() method.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer very helpful Thanks, I have some questions 1- where would I use this `add_action('init', array($this,'my_init');` in class  if in `__construct` still would be the same thing thing write. 2- How can I use the `__invoke` could you give a complete example.

Comment: obviously the order of these things may need to adjust based on the hooks you're working with

Comment: The very first advice should be to use an autoloader instead of manually load classes on different contexts.

Comment: @David - and the reason for that?

Comment: Dynamic autoloading ensures that classes are loaded on _actual demand_. Writing classes with focus on a specific environmental context (e.g. «is admin») leads to inflexible code. However, autoloading reduces own code and thus increases maintainability and makes developers life much easier.

Comment: Do you have an example?